# Best way ever to search a value in a HTML file using C#

Tags: c#, html, string, parsing

I need help to find a token value in a HTML file using C# reading it like text using a string

```html
    </div>
    <div class="nota"><input type="checkbox" id="desactivarComentario" name="desactivarComentario" /><label for="desactivarComentario">No deseo cargar comentarios para los informes. (modificable en <a href="/net/configuracion" target="_self">Configuración</a>)</label></div>    
</div>

<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="XyPDNNtKIHJVg2xhyikMyUcwD26-T9z8HMEWiQh0KXq2vUjMahh2n-nL_fh6_bPJUupSiWc3fcvCdcz-ohZB-4K34WT0-PRXX-MsltnQI8mSYg81kzrFhvByJtLl36D-0" />


<div id="wrapper-resultado" class="cf ly-body">
    <div class="cf barra-consulta">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="fst">
```

In this case the value that I should obtain is: "XyPDNNtKIHJVg2xhyikMyUcwD26-T9z8HMEWiQh0KXq2vUjMahh2n-nL_fh6_bPJUupSiWc3fcvCdcz-ohZB-4K34WT0-PRXX-MsltnQI8mSYg81kzrFhvByJtLl36D-0"

What is the best ever method to find it?

Comment: use **HtmlAgilityPack** to get desired output that you want.

Comment: @ershoaib Thanks, it was solved using IndexOf and Substring methods of String class.

Comment: But what if your html contains multiple `input` and respective `value` attribute. so which you will get by using `IndexOf` and `Substring`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at IndexOf and Substring.

Comment: Thanks y i will try using this method!